# PHP resize image using GD from file_get_contents

Tags: php, gd

I've had a look around various tutorials on resizing images but none quite fit my needs.

I have the following code:

`$raw = file_get_contents($image_url);`

Which then does:

```
file_put_contents($folder.'test'.time().'.png', $raw);
```

But what I'd like to do is resize the image grabbed from the URL and give it a max width of 100px or whatever. Now normally you'd access data for GD through the $_FILES array and just output it to the browser but I need to resize + save to disk. How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the function [imagecreatefromstring()](http://php.net/imagecreatefromstring) to create a GD image resource based on the file grabbed using `file_get_contents()`.

```
$raw = file_get_contents($image_url);
$im  = imagecreatefromstring($raw);

// resize image with GD...

imagepng($im, $folder.'test'.time().'.png'); // save resized image to image.resized.png
```

Hope that helps.